# Use two different views in the same url path in django

Tags: python, html, django, url, view

I got two views.
First one list some reports per user in a sidebar
Second one shows the report in Power BI using embedded code

The thing how can I use both views in one template. THe problem is if I put the path of the first view I can't see the report slected (second view), and vice versa.

Here I'll show images

[image: home page]

[image: This is what it shows when I click the report selected]

[image: This is showed when I put the "reportes" view above "insertar" view]
I'll add some code below

views.py

```
#List reeports per user in the sidebar
def insertar(request):
    usuario = Usuario.objects.get(username=request.session['username'])
    reportes = Reporte.objects.filter(id_usuario=usuario.id_usuario)
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'reportes': reportes})

#Shows the report selected using Powe BI
def reportes(request, titulo):
    usuario = Usuario.objects.get(username=request.session['username'])
    reporte = Reporte.objects.get(titulo=titulo, id_usuario=usuario.id_usuario)
    return render(request, 'reporte.html', {'reporte': reporte})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home', views.insertar, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^home/.*$', views.insertar, name='index'),
    path('home/<titulo>', views.reportes, name='reporte'),
]
```

base.html

```
<body>
    <div class="sidenav">
        {% include "sidebar.html" %}
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
```

reporte.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Listado de Reportes {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<iframe title="{{reporte.titulo}}" width="1024" height="612"
    src="{{reporte.link}}"
    frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true">
</iframe>

{% endblock %}
```

sidebar.html

```
{% for i in reportes %}
<a href="/home/{{i.titulo}}" class="d-block text-light p-3">{{ i.titulo }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have single url entry and its currsponding view function.
in view function you should render a page and pass context dictionary with both report information.

```
def reportes(request, titulo):
    usuario = Usuario.objects.get(username=request.session['username'])
    reporte = Reporte.objects.get(titulo=titulo, id_usuario=usuario.id_usuario)
    reportes = Reporte.objects.filter(id_usuario=usuario.id_usuario)
    return render(request, 'reporte.html', {'reporte': reporte,'reportes':reportes })
```

And in base html you should have two blocks one for left verticle plane and second for next vertivle plane.

```
<body>
    <div class="sidenav">
        {% include "sidebar.html" %}
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        {% block content_1 %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block content_2 %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
```

Now extend this base html page and write your code in respective blocks.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Listado de Reportes {% endblock %}

{% block content_1 %}

<iframe title="{{reporte.titulo}}" width="1024" height="612"
    src="{{reporte.link}}"
    frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true">
</iframe>

{% endblock %}

{% block content_2 %}

<iframe title="{{reporte.titulo}}" width="1024" height="612"
    src="{{reporte.link}}"
    frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true">
</iframe>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi, why do i have to make 2 block contents with the same code in my report.html?

Comment: If you meant to put in block content 1 the sidebar and block content 2 the report, it returned the code in screen

Comment: I typed the render wrongly and I got the raw code instead, but your idea was the correct, thanks <3